# Best stats test for a resume audit study evaluating bias

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, proportion, paired-data, z-test

I am testing an applicant tracking system and giving it resumes that have implicit mention of race, and asking the system to rank them.

There is a control resume with no implicit mention of race.

For the baseline, I ran 20 trials of making the ATS rank identical control resumes (no mention of race). It ranked one of the controls first 2 times, and tied the rest of the times. But this indicates some presence of error in the AI-- meaning I have to test against the baseline.

I have to run my tests against the baseline because the AI showed some presence of error. So in the coin flip metaphor, it's like our "base reality" is that Heads wins 60% of the time, and Tails 40%. So we have to test each trial against "base reality", rather than the all-equal assumption. Most resume audits have an all-equal assumption as their baseline.

Next, I ran 20 trials per race x control, and counted how many times  each was ranked first.

My data therefore looks like:

Test 1 (N=20), Control_a v Control_b, Control_a ranked first 2 times, Tie 18 times

Test 2 (N=20), Control_a v Asian, Control_a ranked first 12 times, Asian ranked first 8 times

Test 3 (N=20), Control_a v Black,

...

Test 7 (N=20), Control_a v Hispanic

**(1) What kind of test should I run statistically support that the system had a preference for the control resume vs the race one compared to the control vs control baseline?**

Next, I applied some modified configurations and re-ran the ATS rankings. The results for the baseline were identical, and in many of the race conditions, the results were ranked first more often.

**(2) What test do I run to show improvement stemming from the ATS customizations?**

Comment: How is the ranking reported by the system? Some numerical score, which? You have paired data, so search this site for that!